# KiCad power symbol name moves when I place it

Tags: kicad

I wanted to create a new power symbol as I prefer the bar-type symbol for my rails.  I duplicated the +3.3V symbol from the power libary, renamed the symbol, moved the text one grid increment down, and drew in a bar.  Everything looks good in the symbol editor, as well as in the placement preview on the schematic.  However, when I actually click to place the symbol, the text jumps one grid increment up, as in the picture below.

[image: Image displaying difference between power symbol when previewed and placed.]

I also created a new 3V3 symbol from scratch, with the same results.  What is causing this behaviour, and how can I avoid it?

Version: (6.0.7), release build

Comment: Random guess: the text is snapping to the grid because the symbol didn't align the text to it.

Comment: I've seen this as well (V6.99/nightlies).  However, I have not been bothered by it recently, so perhaps it's been fixed.  As a work around, I typically place one power symbol of the types I need, then copy-and-paste  from there on out (it's faster than the menu-ing system).  I do understand the initial frustration though.  If you do try 6.99, and it fixes this issue, that would be good info to share...

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen It looks to be resolved in the current nightly.  Version: (6.99.0-4134-ged4a40ee4f)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn field auto placement on/off in the Schematic Editor's preferences under 'Editing Options'

Comment: That fixed it for me.  Thank you.  Would this be considered a work-around, or is the text snapping one grid up the expected behaviour?

Comment: This is expected behavior.  The fields have a padding of 100mil unless that causes collisions with other elements on the schematic.